# DBUnit Rollback After Test

Tags: java, database, rollback, dbunit

Anybody know how to use transactional rollbacks on a DBUnit test.

Everywhere I have looked only uses SprintJUnitClassRunner.

However my tests run with

```
@Runwith(Junit4.class)
```

I basically need to rollback the DB once the test has finished.

Answer (score 1):

dbUnit's purpose is to cleanup the database tables before and after the test runs, so rolling back the transaction isn't necessary.  Refer to [DatabaseOperation](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/components.html#DatabaseOperation) for the options.